# I need to write content from f.write to be written in play.txt file. data_file is data from entry box with 8 arguments. KIVY only please

Tags: python, for-loop, mobile, kivy, kivy-language

```
with open('play.txt', 'a+') as data_file:
            for i in data_file:
                f.write("First game, first court: " + data_file[0] + " and" + data_file[1] + " against " + data_file[2] + " and" + data_file[
                    3] + ".")
                f.write("First game, second court: " + data_file[4] + " and" + data_file[5] + " against " + data_file[6] + " and" + data_file[
                    7] + ".")
```

- I don't know how to write it in play.txt file*

> Thanks for help! <3

Comment: When you open a file in "append plus" mode (`a+`) the file pointer is positioned at the end of the file. There are no lines left to itrerate so the for loop doesn't run. In this case you likely want "r" mode. Looks like you are using suggestions from a previous question you posted but that question had lots of problems and the answers weren't any better.

Comment: Another problem is that `data_file` is a file object, not the data itself. You can't index it. `data_file[0]` isn't a thing. You also don't show what `f` is. Are you reading from one file and writing changed lines to another? Is one of these a CSV (that is, what do you expect `data_file[0]` to be?).

Comment: You'll have more luck sorting these problems out if you write test programs focused on small problems. For example, I wrote up something that I think represents this problem here: https://pastebin.com/tdrqjeh9. That's a self-contained program that demonstrates writing the file.